# PostgreSQL JDBC Call is very slow, but the same using psql is fine

Tags: performance, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

I have a SQL-query I call using JDBC from an app deployed on JBoss. (To be honest, this is some native query at Spring-Data repository).

The query plan is optimal, I can run it using `psql` on the app server, and the execution time will be 0.8sec (the DB server is relatively slow). So no network slowdowns.

The same query from the JBoss server with the same parameters takes more than 3 seconds to execute.

Profiling using JProfiler shows that the slowest call is `org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery()` - 3.3 secs
Seems other queries are slowed down as well but not that much.

There is no other users and processes on JBoss. The connection pool is free.

Why the same query is so slow with JDBC but fast using `psql`? How to debug such kind of problems?

PostgreSQL 9.3 Linux x64. Java8. The latest JDBC client. JBoss EAP 7.

Comment: did you figure this out?